# Receiving a reference error in Xcode stating that an object is not defined.

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, json, parse-platform

I'm writing parse cloud code that pings eBay, returns JSON data with item results, and then parses that data and stores the top two categories into an array. The query sent to eBay is based on whatever a user inputs in the itemSearch bar in my iOS app. When I attempt to send a query like "iPhone", it gives me an error stating the following:

```
ReferenceError: data is not defined
at Object.Parse.Cloud.httpRequest.success (main.js:34:11)
at Object.<anonymous> (<anonymous>:565:19) (Code: 141, Version: 1.2.18)
```

The objective-c code is as follows:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if (sender != self.nextButton) return;
    if (self.itemSearch.text.length > 0) {

        [PFCloud callFunctionInBackground:@"eBayCategorySearch"
                           withParameters:@{@"item": self.itemSearch.text}
                                    block:^(NSString *result, NSError *error) {
                                        if (!error) {

                                            NSLog(@"Successfully pinged eBay!");
                                        }

                                    }];


    }

    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.

}
```

The cloud code (main.js) running on Parse is as follows:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("eBayCategorySearch", function(request, response) {
          url = 'http://svcs.ebay.com/services/search/FindingService/v1';

  Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
      url: url,
      params: {     
       'OPERATION-NAME' : 'findItemsByKeywords', 
       'SERVICE-VERSION' : '1.12.0',
       'SECURITY-APPNAME' : '*APP ID GOES HERE*',
       'GLOBAL-ID' : 'EBAY-US',
       'RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT' : 'JSON',
       'itemFilter(0).name=ListingType' : 'itemFilter(0).value=FixedPrice',
       'keywords' : request.params.item,

        // your other params
     },
      success: function (httpResponse) {

          response.success(httpResponse.data)

          // count number of times each unique primaryCategory shows up (based on categoryId), return top two (done with a for loop?)

          var userCategories = {};

          data.findItemsByKeywordsResponse.searchResult[0].item.forEach(function(item) 
          {
          var id = item.primaryCategory[0].categoryId;
          if (userCategories[id]) userCategories[id]++;
          else userCategories[id] = 1;
          });

          var top2 = Object.keys(userCategories).sort(function(a, b) 
            {return userCategories[b]-userCategories[a]; }).slice(0, 2);
          console.log('Top two categories: ' + top2.join(', '));


      // deal with success and respond to query
  },
            error: function (httpResponse) {
                console.log('error!!!');
                console.error('Request failed with response code ' + httpResponse.status);
            }
       });
});
```

I believe it may be because the JSON isn't being returned properly, but I'm not sure how I would make sure, or how it can be fixed. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Google json validator and you'll see a few sites available to validate your json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first step is to log the value of the httpResponse object. Update your `success` callback to log the value:

```
  success: function (httpResponse) {
      console.log('Received successful response.'); // <---
      console.log(httpResponse); // <---
      response.success(httpResponse.data)

      // count number of times each unique primaryCategory shows up (based on categoryId), return top two (done with a for loop?)

      var userCategories = {};

      data.findItemsByKeywordsResponse.searc
```

You can read about how to log data here: https://parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide#logging

And you can find out more about reading your logs here: https://parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide#clt-logs

Comment: Adding the above resulted in it logging 'Received successful response.', however I'm still getting the error I mentioned above.

Comment: Is anything logged directly after that? Does httpResponse contain a value?

Comment: This is what's found in my logs:

`Input: {"item":"iphone"}
  Failed with: ReferenceError: data is not defined
    at Object.Parse.Cloud.httpRequest.success (main.js:35:11)
    at Object.<anonymous> (<anonymous>:565:19)
I2014-03-28T04:41:48.853Z] Received successful response.`

Comment: I just checked your user page and noticed that you just joined 9 days ago. Welcome to Stack Overflow.